# Receiving objects in springboot using the PAYPAL REST API

Tags: java, spring-boot, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

My first attempt to integrate PAYPAL into JAVA. But it seems that PAYPAL has recently archived many of its API libraries. Well, I tried to follow the tutorial at https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/webhooks/

If you need the official example code in here, it in the end.

**Note:** I can't debug it in local tests, so I use ngrok to simulate HTTPS.

And there i got a false response

```
      Boolean result = Event.validateReceivedEvent(apiContext,getHeadersInfo(req), getBody(req));
```

How should I extract payload it, I mean I didn't find a subscription or order or customer class to get the response data. Am I missing something?

```
package com.paypal.api.payments.servlet;
import com.paypal.api.payments.CreditCard;
import com.paypal.api.payments.Event;
import com.paypal.api.payments.util.ResultPrinter;
import com.paypal.base.Constants;
import com.paypal.base.rest.APIContext;
import com.paypal.base.rest.PayPalRESTException;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SignatureException;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import static com.paypal.api.payments.util.SampleConstants.*;
public class ValidateWebhookServlet extends HttpServlet {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1 L;
  private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ValidateWebhookServlet.class);
  public static final String WebhookId = "4JH86294D6297924G";
  @Override
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
  throws ServletException, IOException {
    doPost(req, resp);
  }
  // ##Validate Webhook
  @Override
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
  throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
      // ### Api Context
      APIContext apiContext = new APIContext(clientID, clientSecret, mode);
      // Set the webhookId that you received when you created this webhook.
      apiContext.addConfiguration(Constants.PAYPAL_WEBHOOK_ID, WebhookId);
      Boolean result = Event.validateReceivedEvent(apiContext, getHeadersInfo(
        req), getBody(req));
      System.out.println("Result is " + result);
      LOGGER.info("Webhook Validated:  " + result);
      ResultPrinter.addResult(req, resp, "Webhook Validated:  ", CreditCard.getLastRequest(),
        CreditCard.getLastResponse(), null);
    } catch (PayPalRESTException e) {
      LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
      ResultPrinter.addResult(req, resp, "Webhook Validated:  ", CreditCard.getLastRequest(),
        null, e.getMessage());
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
      LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
      ResultPrinter.addResult(req, resp, "Webhook Validated:  ", CreditCard.getLastRequest(),
        null, e.getMessage());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
      LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
      ResultPrinter.addResult(req, resp, "Webhook Validated:  ", CreditCard.getLastRequest(),
        null, e.getMessage());
    } catch (SignatureException e) {
      LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
      ResultPrinter.addResult(req, resp, "Webhook Validated:  ", CreditCard.getLastRequest(),
        null, e.getMessage());
    }
  }
  // Simple helper method to help you extract the headers from HttpServletRequest object.
  private static Map < String, String > getHeadersInfo(HttpServletRequest request) {
    Map < String, String > map = new HashMap < String, String > ();
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    Enumeration headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();
    while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
      String key = (String) headerNames.nextElement();
      String value = request.getHeader(key);
      map.put(key, value);
    }
    return map;
  }
  // Simple helper method to fetch request data as a string from HttpServletRequest object.
  private static String getBody(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
    String body;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    try {
      InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();
      if (inputStream != null) {
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        char[] charBuffer = new char[128];
        int bytesRead = -1;
        while ((bytesRead = bufferedReader.read(charBuffer)) > 0) {
          stringBuilder.append(charBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
      } else {
        stringBuilder.append("");
      }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      throw ex;
    } finally {
      if (bufferedReader != null) {
        try {
          bufferedReader.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
          throw ex;
        }
      }
    }
    body = stringBuilder.toString();
    return body;
  }
}
```

Comment: Plenty of debugging to be done on your end, but begin by logging everything being passed to validateReceivedEvent. It looks like this is using the old PayPal-Java-SDK which was deprecated years ago. You should adapt the old Java pseudocode from that documentation to not make use of that old SDK.

Comment: Yes, it is because I removed these outdated codes that I don't know how to get information about orders, customers, etc. for PAYLOAD. It seems that PAYPAL returns this information in a string instead of an object or a separate CLASS

Comment: The REST APIs return a JSON string, yes.  Parse it using JSONObject , "Gson" for Java, or similar